# ruby web scraping nokogiri from "Load more" button

Tags: ruby, web, load, nokogiri, screen-scraping

I wish to get list of links given on contact name  from page health.usnews.com/doctors/pain-management-specialists/alabama/adamsville

Shows only 10 results and wish to extract more then need to click on "Load more"

Can you give bit idea how to do it?

I already code like as following and its showing result of 10 records. Wish to get all links given on contact name by clicking "Load more"

Please help me if you can.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'
require 'openssl'
require 'json'

data_array = []
url = 'http://health.usnews.com/doctors/pain-management-specialists/alabama/adamsville'

nokogiri_object = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url).read)
fparse = nokogiri_object.xpath("//h3/a[@class='search-result-link']/@href")

fparse.each do |a|
  post_name = a.text
  furl = 'http://health.usnews.com' + post_name
  data_array.push(furl)
end

CSV.open('yp.csv', 'w', { :col_sep => "\n "}) do |csv|
  csv << data_array
end
```

Comment: There's some ajax loading happening there so you'll need something with javascript. Like selenium or capybara or phantomjs.

Comment: can you please check it; i mentioned source url and code. If you can give me exact code will be really helpful as i am very new to this language.

Comment: "If you can give me exact code will be really helpful as i am very new to this language." SO isn't a "give me the code" site. Your experience level isn't important, your willingness to research and learn and try is. Please read the linked pages in "[ask]" as they'll help you understand how to ask better.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not going to do it for you. Your options are to either learn this stuff or hire somebody to do it for you.

Comment: i wish to learn this. I spend over 2-3 days but not gets success. i really need your help. You are only the hope for me now. I really thankful to you lifetime if you can help me. I really tired it but due to not much technical knowledge i wasn't able to succeed. Even i did lot many web research though not found any option for same. That is only the reason i contact you. Please understand.